# Regex to find 2 numbers in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following strings:

```
10-0
5-8
1-19
```

I want to get a "True" if the strings contains [num]-[num], else it should return "False".

How should I do it with regex?

Comment: till how many digits can the [num] go?

Comment: For future reference, this might help you with this kind of question in future:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it shoudl be like this `^((\d+)-(\d+))$`

```
Regex objPattern=new Regex(@"((\d+)-(\d+))$");
bool val = objPattern.IsMatch("12-34");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to work with regexes in c# but here is a regex that matches your pattern: `\d+-\d+`

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\d+)-(\d+)")
```

Comment: Your regex will only match if the [num]-[num] is at the end of the string.

Comment: He wants to match strings that include the pattern so I would remove both the start and end symbols.

Comment: well, i thought pattern [num]-[num] is fixed. But you are right, requirement is similar to String.Contains.